# no sound on iec958 S/PDIF input - sound card USB CM106

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, input

**Issue :**
no sound on digital input S/PDIF / IEC958.

**Device / software :**
USB external sound card : CM106 - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - GUI : Gnome-FlashBack

**Config audio :**
FreeBox Player (french internet TV provider) - digital output S/PDIF ==[TosLink]=> sound card - digital input S/PDIF

FreeBox Player config : Main sound output S/PDIF, with or without passthrough

---

The digital input iec958 is visible within graphical pavucontrol or pulse command line answers. But the sound meter (vumeter) remain empty, no sound, no signal.

I do not have any other sound device to check the FreeBox player S/PDIF output.

Is there any file I could check, in /sys or /proc or /dev, to see if there is any digital signal/data ?

The iec958 input is visible, but no sound/signal ? Why ?

Is there something specific to do to make it works.

How to troubleshoot this issue ? Where starting ? What steps ?

It makes a lot of week-ends I try to fixe it, reading forums, I cannot remember all I tried and detail it here.
I will answer your questions about this troubleshoot.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you see an input level in pavucontrol, then your card is receiving the output, and you should be able to record it.

In my experience, there is no way to get pulseaudio to configure your card to pass this through to line out for example, other than setting up constant recording/playback.

You might be able to change this using amixer, but this is highly card specific, and it is possible that your card simply cannot do this, so you might have a constant (cpu-consuming) loopback solution.

If your problem is that you don't see anything on the input, then you will need to configure your card: in pavucontrol, change the profile under configuration to something that includes "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input".

**Update:**

I have experimented with my CM106 device, and I think the linux driver does not support mixing spdif in into the output.

However, according to the data sheet (http://www.steila.com/usb4io/CMedia/CM106--L_F-Datasheet-1.3.pdf), the card does support it, and indeed, some experimenting let me enable it, by writing a value into register 1 that enables SPDIFMIX (hidraw1 is the hidraw device corresponding to the usb sound card, check dmesg when plugging it in):

```
perl -e 'print pack "H*", "002001b001"' >/dev/hidraw1
```

This sets the register to the power-on default value (00b0) + SPDIFMIX enabled (01b0) (in little-endian).

The following shell skript hack sets the bit on every "USB Sound Device" - it might be dangerous when used with the wrong card:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /sys/class/hidraw || exit
for dev in *; do
   set "$dev"/device/input/*/name
   read name <"$1"
   if [ "$name" = "USB Sound Device" ]; then
      echo "enabling SPDIFMIX on $dev"
      printf "\000\040\001\260\001" >/dev/"$dev"
   fi
done
```